# how to find orthogonal vectors of 3 Dimensional point

Tags: geometry, vector-analysis

If $A(3, 4, 5)$ and $B(7, 10, 12)$ are two end points of a line segment. I know that vector $V_1=B-A$  i.e $V_1=(4, 6, 7)$ then how to find the other two orthogonal vectors of this?

Comment: This smells like Vector Geometry homework.

Comment: no not a vector geometry homework ... i just provided some example for better understanding.........and just now understood that there will be infinite vectors orthogonal to the given vector

Answer (score 2):

Three non-colinear points are needed to define a plane, but you only really have two here.  If you just want to find a couple of arbitrary vectors orthogonal vectors, just pick any third point, `C`, not colinear with `A` and `B`, then `W = (A-C)×(B-C)` (where `×` is the cross product) is orthogonal to the line segment connecting `A` and `B` since any plane containing `A` and `B` also contains the line segment connecting them.

If you need a third vector `U` orthogonal to `V = A-B` and to `W`, then just set `U = V×W`

The first step is probably easiest if you pick `C` as the origin (again if it's not colinear with `A` and `B`); this reduces to setting `W = (A×B)`.

More information is available both at [Wolfram](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/CrossProduct.html) and [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross_product).

Comment: could you explain this approach for the above mentioned example in question.....Thanks.

Comment: @user1198477: So that I know how detailed to get, do you know what a cross product is?

Answer (score 0):

Use vector product:  `V1 ^ V2`, if they aren't collateral, it will give you an orthogonal vector.

Answer (score 0):

There are not two unique orthogonal vectors, there are an infinity of them.

Consider V1 as the vector normal to a plane (in Euclidean space).  Any two orthogonal vectors lying in that surface will be orthogonal to V1.

Imagine a clock face.  Put the hands at 12 and 3.  You now have a set of 3 orthogonal vectors, V1, 12'o'clock, and 3'o'clock.  Rotate the clock face, and you get a different set.  Mirror-image the clock face, and you get another set.  And so on...